# What tag should I use for ambiguity resolution?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've asked a few questions like [this most recent one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/what-is-the-gift-of-god-in-eph-28), in which the weight of the question has to do with resolving an ambiguity. In the example linked, Paul talks about grace, salvation, and faith, and then refers to one of them using the pronoun "it".

I'd like to be able to tag questions along these lines, but I'm not sure what the tag should be called. It is a matter of parsing the sentence, but I can't tell if [parsing](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) would be helpful. It could be called [analysis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis), but that is obviously far too broad.

Can anyone suggest a tag that would communicate the work that needs to be done in these cases?

Comment: I went and tagged a few questions as [tag:ambiguity]. If anyone has better ideas it is easy to move the whole tag over